# Translation of "How did you go there?"

Tags: переклад, from-english

I am aware that Ukrainian has no word for "go" that does not imply a form of transit.

So what verb would be substituted for "go" in the translation of:

> How did you *go* there?

Comment: Is it the same as *How did you get there?*

Comment: Do you mean in the sense of "by which means" or "by which route"? I would think if you mean mean "route" = добрались оr "means" = дістались; one has the sense of plodding along "добрались" the other has a sense of "to arrive at"

Answer (score 10):

You are right, Ukrainian specifies whether you go on foot, *іти*, or on/in a kind of transport, *їхати*. Still, Ukrainian *does* have a verb which generalizes over *іти* and *їхати*, and that is *дістатися*, "to get", and that is the word you use if you are not sure how far the place is. That is why:

> "How did you *go* there?" is "Як ви туди *дісталися*?"

Comment: And another word [`добиратися`](http://sum.in.ua/s/dobyratysja): `Як ви туди добрались?`.